# Ordered data structure with efficient push, iteration and random pop/drain

Tags: data-structures, efficiency

I need a data structure `d` with somewhat conflicting requirements. What are the different tradeoffs I could pick?

The same algorithm will be repeatedly done on each time step:

- `push` one new element to the right (so all elements remain naturally ordered by the date they came into the data structure).
- `update` all elements. I mean *iterate* (in any order or parallel) and *mutate* in place.
- based on the result of the update, `drain` random elements in order (new or old). I mean that some will have to be both *returned* in order to user and *removed* from `d`.
- user should also easily `iterate` in order over remaining elements.

For instance, think of a bunch of fruit that takes a random time to ripen. One new piece of fruit is spawned each day. And each day we need to collect (ordered) ripe fruit, while keeping remaining pieces of fruit ordered by age.

Is there a dedicated data structure?
If not, is there a pattern for this case?
If not, what are the different tradeoffs I'll have to deal with? Is there any assumption I could make on the data (like drain frequency) to help me choose?
(for instance, I suspect that many pieces of fruit will be ripe on the first or the first few update(s), and only a few will last longer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tree data structures allow for O(log n) random access and for easy traversal. A naive binary tree likely has worse performance than using a flat array though, but you are not forced to use binary trees.

You can implement k-ary trees that contain an array of items per tree node. The size parameter k is tunable. For sufficiently large k you get similar memory locality benefits to an array, but smaller values of k make random deletions faster.

Similarly, you can upgrade a linked list by not storing a single value per link, but an array of items per link. Of course, linked lists have O(n) random access, regardless of such strategies.

Another strategy to improve memory locality is a kind of arena allocation: store all nodes in a dynamic array and link them by index. Not only will all nodes be close in memory, but the links can possibly be small integer indices instead of full-sized pointers. If your entries have a “empty” representation, then you could also store the nodes in order, and iterate over the array while skipping empty items. Occasionally, you'll have to re-compact the node array so that there aren't large holes in the middle.

If the removed items are not random but are likely to occur at end (so that your data structure behaves like a probabilistic FIFO queue), and your entries have an empty representation that can be skipped over, then a circular buffer might be a good fit. Again, you would have to occasionally re-compact the buffer.

You actually assume the reverse: that many items will be removed quickly,
but a few items will remain longer. Here, it might be useful to take inspiration from garbage collection strategies, e.g. generational GC: Store the young generation in a simple data structure like a dynamic array. You can zero out entries when removing them, and compact the items by moving them to the front. Occasionally, move the frontmost items to a separate data structure for the long-lived generation. Depending on your access patterns and on the sizes of the generations, a more sophisticated data structure may be appropriate for the old generation.

Comment: Thank you for this thorough overview of tradeoffs involved :) I'll try a few of them when it'll be time to compare approaches against a benchmark, and stick with a simple list while prototyping.

Comment: Great comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a doubly-linked list. Appending, (sequential) enumerating and deleting are all quick operations.

Parallel algorithms on doubly-linked lists are harder. If you somehow can't meet performance goals with the sequential enumeration, you could probably utilize a list of lists, but that makes all operations a bit tricky.

Comment: It does, but I'm afraid that doubly-linked list suffer from a quite [bad](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.LinkedList.html) [reputation](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/) online (need heap allocation on each `push`, bad use of CPU cache..). People write that we only truly need them in like .01% niche cases. Do you think this ripening fruit problem is one of those? I mean, am I.. *legitimate* if I use one here? X)

Comment: Heap allocators can be quite fast and efficient, and whether cache performance is an issue should be determined by actual measurements, not by theorizing. I'm not sure your ripening fruit problem is something that you actually need to solve or whether it is a toy problem created for this question. And to be honest, I couldn't care less about bad reputation of data structures :-) Use what works, switch to something which works better when provably necessary.

Comment: This sounds sound. Thank you for reassuring me ;) I'll go for a linked list and benchmark all this later. Cheers!